# HTACCESS Redirection Clarification

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect my web page using .htaccess. For all the requests, I want to redirect to http to https. But if the URL contains substring `api`, I don't want this redirection. I have tried following but it always redirecting to https.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond  %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} api
    RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you sure your rule redirects all requests to https?

Comment: For me, it redirects only if **api** is present in uri.

Comment: Its redirects all url. The condition given for have no effect

Comment: put `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/api/` instead of the one with `%{REQUEST_URI}`. This is because finally it gets `index.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead for substring 'api' anywhere in the URI:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !api
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

And change it like this if you only want to exclude calls like '.../api/...'

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/api\/
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, all url are redirected to https. "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/api/" has no effect.

Comment: plz try the new one again, with masked '/'  if that still doesn't do the job i'd assume that the rewrite to https is coming from somewhere else. because this rule definitely only works when the substring `api` is not in the rewuested URI. so example.com/path/for/test should be rewritten to https and example.com/path/to/api/test shouldn't